# Rerender an apex:pageBlockSection from an apex:actionFunction

Tags: visualforce, rerender, actionfunction, rendered, pageblocksection

i have a javascript function that must delete an item from a cart and it's work well, i have a command button in which there is a render already and i want that my javascript function reREnder a section in my visualforce page.

This is my action

```
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:actionFunction name="remove" action="{!remove}" />
                    <apex:actionFunction name="renderABC"  reRender="try"/>  
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

this is my pageblock that i want to rerender: `<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="try" >`

this is my javascript function:

```
function updateCart() { 
var remove = window.confirm("Do you want to delete all");
if (remove){        
alert ('i'am deleting... ');
remove();
renderABC();
return remove;`
  }
}
```

i tried with only one apex actionFunction but it doesnt work the same, there is somethings that i am not taking in serious consideration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u tried puttting that section in outputPanel and then rerender it from action function?

Comment: Yes, but it's seem not working yet

Comment: can you post full code?

Comment: yes, code about controller or visualforce page?

Comment: all would help us solve better

Comment: i have edit my same post over, i hope it can help to solve my problem

Comment: @Amiga500 - You will need to re render the parent container. Without your full page markup (for that section) we cannot get more specific

Comment: the parent container is the parent of my <apex:pageBlockSectio right? @Eric

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a single function to do this:

```
function updateCart() { 
var remove = window.confirm("Do you want to delete all");
if (remove){        
remove();
return remove;`
  }
}
```

then

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:actionFunction name="remove" action="{!remove}" rerender="try"/>

     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: with only one it explode in one generic visualforce error page

Comment: @Amiga500 - then something else is going on because this is the way it should